# Changing the edit form in Joomla 3.x for specific article category

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I have a bunch of articles in a Joomla 3.1 site that all live under a single category.

I'm creating a specific editor group for each article, ie a small group of users will have edit permissions for 1 article.

I'd like to do something so that when an article that is within the prescribed category (not all articles) is edited, the user (editor) sees a short block of text at the top of the edit page.

Is that possible within Joomla or would I have to edit the PHP file that creates the form?

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish this using a tool like content templater. http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/code-snippets/7152